# Диалог сохранения в Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, c++

Возможно мой вопрос покажется глупым или несущественным но все же. Недавно начал программировать на С++ в Eclipse. При каждом запуске порграммы выдается сообщение о том, что исходный код был изменен, не желаю ли я сохранить изменения. До этого программировал в Visual Studio, так вот там это было несколько удобнее - запуск приложения осуществлялся всего нажатием одной клавиши F5, а здесь приходится жать сразу две (Ctrl+F11) и кроме того еще нажимать кнопку в этом диалоге. Можно как-нибудь избавиться от этого диалога?

Comment: Window->Preferences->Keys->Scheme

Можешь выбрать Microsoft Visual Studio и любимые комбинации вернутся :)

Comment: Насколько я помню на этом окошке еще должна быть галочка «Всегда сохранять файлы перед запуском», ее ставишь и окно больше не появляется.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Window => Preferences => Run/Debug => Launching => Save required dirty editors before launching ставите переключатель в положение "Always"

Должно помочь. Ну и еще на всякий случай Window => Preferences => General => Workspace => Save automatically before build  (не знаю, насколько это важно, возможно, что вовсе не имеет значения - у меня уже этот флаг ранее уже был выставлен)

Впрочем, как показала практика, последний пункт значения все же не имеет

Comment: спасибо помогло